# Mac OSX Apple Script, How do I make Apple Script push keys on an application

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, applescript

What I am trying to do is make my character run up 50 steps then down 50 steps repeatedly using the up key and the down key. I know how to utilize system events to push keys and I know how to tell applications to do certain things but what I put together so far is not looking right. I am pretty much new to this, and I am trying to learn a bit, please help!!

Comment: What goes wrong when you try? It's hard to help you more without knowing what isn't working.

Comment: Alright so my application is PokeMMO and I got an AppleScript Error it says PokeMMO got an error: AppleEvent timed out

Answer (score 2):

You might also add a delay somewhere in the loop to make it easier to stop the script:

```
activate application "TextEdit"
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if the script is run with a keyboard shortcut
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while name of (process 1 where frontmost is true) is "TextEdit"
        repeat 50 times
            key code 126 -- up
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        repeat 50 times
            key code 125 -- down
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
end tell
```

See Events.h or [my website](http://lri.me/applescript.html) for the key codes.

Comment: Alright so the delay one does not include the application in it. Also, the application requires a login at the beginning that I can do myself so is there a way I can activate the applescript program after I have already logged in so it doesn't have to activate PokeMMO it just like tells PokeMMO to press the keys?

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Your App Name Here"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat 50 times
            key code 126
            -- up
        end repeat
        repeat 50 times
            key code 125
            -- down
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Alright so my application is PokeMMO and I got an AppleScript Error

Comment: it says PokeMMO got an error: AppleEvent timed out

Comment: That is exactly what happens

Comment: Try adding the delay as @Lauri Ranta suggests. With the apps I've tried it with, I don't get a problem, but I've never worked with "PokeMMO".

Comment: Alright so the delay one does not include the application in it. Also, the application requires a login at the beginning that I can do myself so is there a way I can activate the applescript program after I have already logged in so it doesn't have to activate PokeMMO it just like tells PokeMMO to press the keys?